# Why does the Typescript documentation suggests declaring a class decorator in the following way?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

Recently, I've been trying to wrap my head around why the writers of the Typescript documentation have chosen the following [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#:%7E:text=Next%20we%20have%20an%20example%20of%20how%20to%20override%20the%20constructor%20to%20set%20new%20defaults.) for class decorators:

```
function reportableClassDecorator<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
  return class extends constructor {
    reportingURL = "http://www...";
  };
}
```

I am particularly interested in this bit: `new (...args: any[]): {}`

Why does the constructor signature have `{}` as its return type? To me, it seems like `unknown` or `object` would be a better choice here, it feels more descriptive.

I understand that putting `{}` as the return type of a function means that it can return pretty much anything. However, I don't understand why the documentation recommends using it like this.

Can anyone help me discover what am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, you can't use `unknown` because `class extends ctor {...}` will complain unless `ctor` constructs something object-like with statically known keys.  You can use `object` if you want.  But I believe the decorator documentation was originally written before `object` and `unknown` even existed in the language, and where `{}` was the closest thing to a top type that TS had.

Comment: @jcalz The example was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/commit/0e23118a36cdd2c99817662f9acae46170ef0036#diff-4a58d532fa1ce743cde9eb5d20d053f1a912dc1a394485742217a5e017739c34), which contains a couple of linked issues as well.

Comment: The name of the example was changed (from `classDecorator` to `reportableClassDecorator`) but that's not really where it was introduced, since the `{}` part was not touched by the diff.  I've been trying to chase it backwards in time but of course TypeScript-Website only goes back to late 2019 or something so I'm still looking.  Also, I think mixins (which support `class x extends y {...}` expressions) and `object` were actually both introduced in TS2.2, but they were independent PRs and so mixins didn't really know about `object` or couldn't rely on it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the inisights! So would you say that ```object``` would actually be a better option?

Comment: All right, [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/commit/95fb87e06fda85204d90696bb7a9a652ca1bee04) is the commit that introduced it. Interestingly, [the mixin classes PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743) did seem to know about `object`, at least in the comments, before it was merged, so I'm not sure why they used `{}` instead of `object`, other than maybe `object` was still too new?

Comment: "would you say that `object` would actually be a better option?" Probably? Although some people and their linters [discourage](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/d3587857227526594f05a1d96515afe3c2ee0545/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules/ban-types.ts#L101-L102) using `object` [for some reason](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732#issuecomment-886221640), so maybe not? I can only go down one rabbit hole at a time and I am still researching to see if there is an authoritative answer to the existing question.

Comment: Aha, 2.2.0 didn't support using `object` in a mixin... this was [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13805) for 2.2.1.  So I'm going to say that they didn't use `object` in the docs because it didn't work when the docs were written and people had been used to using `{}` as a pseudo-top-type for a while.  And that the documentation isn't *recommending* that anyone use `{}`; it's just an example.

Comment: Nice findings! I was just looking for a way to "properly" use a class decorator that replaces the constructor of thar class. And I assumed that the documentation would be the best place to look for a suitable example.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is not `null` or `undefined` is assignable to the empty type `{}` so it may be a bit too wide for a constructor's return type. Maybe `object` is the generic type that would represent the most accurately the return value of a constructor.

Comment: Does this really answer the question, which is about why the linked documentation uses `{}` instead of `object`?

Comment: No, the answer to that question is probably that they don't recommend it, they just used it in an example.

Comment: Ok, so the Typescript documentation might need some work then...I find the ```{}``` to be really confusing. I begin to understand why they chose that there.